# How to modify _renderContainer($name)

Tags: magento-2.0.4

I want to modify the method `_renderContainer($name)` in the class `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout` so that I can pass it another argument and add this to the construction of the container.

The end goal is to add a custom attribute to the container.

Plugin's don't work here I believe and trying a preference I think would need to move huge amounts of classes into my new namespace. Thanks.